# Unordered list styling with HTML markup

Tags: android

In the link [String Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) I came to know that Android supports only Bold, Italic and Underline styling with HTML markup, and I have seen some Application that displays Unordered list inside the AlertDialog, so tried to implement that in my application as

in my String.xml, I've given

```
<String name="unorderedlist">Different Types &lt;ul> &lt;li>T ype 1 &lt;/li> &lt;li> Type 2 &lt;/li> &lt;/ul> </String>
```

in my activity, I tried to display it inside my AlertDialog as follows

```
String formatedString=String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.unorderedlist), "");
myAlertDialogBuilder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(formatedString));
```

Its not working, So is there any other way to do this, give me some guidance.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saved the file that should be displayed as HTML page an HTML file inside the assets folder and designed a Custom Dialog box with a WebView and in the Java file I loaded the HTML file from the local resource and displayed it inside WebView.

Answer (score 0):

Bulleted list can be simply created by using the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags in the string resource.

**DO NOT USE** *setText(Html.fromHtml(string))* to set the string in code! Just set the string normally in xml or by using setText(*string*).

E.g:

*strings.xml file*

```
<string name="str1"><ul> <li><i>first</i> item</li> <li>item 2</li> </ul></string>
```

*layout.xml file*

```
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/str1"
    />
```

It will produce the following result:

- *first* item
- item 2

Following tags are supported like this (directly embedded in the string resource):

- <a> (supports attributes "href")
- <annotation>
- <b>
- <big>
- <font> (supports attributes "height", "size", "fgcolor" and "bicolor", as integers)
- <i>
- <li>
- <marquee>
- <small>
- <strike>
- <sub>
- <sup>
- <tt>
- <u>

Comment: Is there any reference available for the above mentioned tags that been supported by Android natively because I didn't see anything related to it under [Styling with HTML markup](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Comment: HI Abhishek, I think your answer is right, but if I modify directly the styles.xml whith the ul li tags and the bullets are showed, but all at the beginning of the sentence...e.g. if I have two bullets  this is the result: - - and the two string one after the other...any suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

Try looking in APIDemos > App> Alert Dialog Samples. You will find various examples on how to use Alert Dialogs.

For the code:

it is inside `com.example.android.apis.app` package -> `AlertDialogSamples.java`.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to display Unordered list.

Comment: If you want to display it in a Dialog then go with the answer OR if you want to display in your activity, use a "ListView". You can find lots of tutorials on how to implement a listview in android on google.

Comment: Dialog, TextView, ListView is not a matter,  I'm asking is it possible to display Unordered list, actually I can able to display Bold, Italics, Underline which are supported HTML elements in android, but I've seen unordered list in some application so I'm trying to implement that.

Comment: Okay but Thanks for your answer, may be it'll be useful at some point.